# Collect optional class fields in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Optional fields in TypeScript classes are not accessible via the `getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.keys` methods.
Is there a way to collect the optional field names of a class in TypeScript?
Thank you.

Comment: Optional properties doesn't exist on actual object unless they are initiated. So I guess it's not possible. But I'm not sure though.

Comment: You mean at runtime? No, if you didn't put the property in the object, yo can't find it. Use `| undefined` instead of an optional property.